# Adding Offset to 'contours'

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, contour

I'm working in Windows 10, with Python 3.8 and OpenCV 4.5, and creating an artificial dataset to train a Convolutional Neural Network. In one step I need to translate a `contour` structure, but I'm stucked at this problem and I can't fix.

I need to translate a `contour`  by `x_offset` and `y_offset`. But I'm having a hard time with `np.array` types and the way OpenCV organize `contours`.

I read in the OpenCV docs ([findContours()](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga17ed9f5d79ae97bd4c7cf18403e1689a)) that contours are stored as vectors, this shows us that these points need to be arranged somehow, and on my tries I'm probably losing the arrangement, because I'm getting this error:

```
error: OpenCV(4.5.3) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'drawContours'
> Overload resolution failed:
>  - contours is not a numpy array, neither a scalar
>  - Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'contours'
```

So I went to a much simpler file and recreated the first example on that [Getting Started with Contours](https://opencv24-python-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contours_begin/py_contours_begin.html#) site:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

im = cv2.imread('test.jpg',cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
imgray = cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(imgray,127,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
for data in contours:
    print (f"The contours have this data: {data}")
cv2.drawContours(im,contours,-1,(0,255,0),3)
cv2.imshow('output',im)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image: Square Recognized in Binary Image]

When I print `contours`, I get this as result:

```
[array([[[207, 146]],

       [[207, 455]],

       [[603, 455]],

       [[603, 146]]], dtype=int32)]
```

I'm trying to keep the structure, but remap the points using `x_offset` and `y_offset`, so my result should be something like:

```
[array([[[207 + x_offset, 146 + y_offset]],

       [[207 + x_offset, 455 + y_offset]],

       [[603 + x_offset, 455 + y_offset]],

       [[603 + x_offset, 146 + y_offset]]], dtype=int32)]
```

[image: Contour with Offset]

Can someone help with an algorithm to perform this operation without losing the structure of the `contour`? So I can use `drawContours` to draw this translated `contour`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have to add your X and Y offset to every contour as a tuple:

```
x_offset, y_offset = 5, 3
for contour in contours:
  # contour with new offset is created
  new_contour = contour + (x_offset, y_offset)
  # draw the new contour on the image
  cv2.drawContours(im,new_contour,-1,(0,255,0),3)
```

I guess the data structure of `contours` got you confused. `contours` is a tuple. Every contour identified is stored as an individual tuple. The points for each contour is stored inside these tuples.